# Proving that $H_1-H_0$ is idempotent

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, idempotents

I want to prove that for symmetric, idempotent matrices $H_1$ and $H_0$ (these are "hat matrices" of a linear regression model), $(H_1-H_0)=(H_1-H_0)^2$, in order to show a property of a distribution. So far, I've only found that the square equals $H_1-2H_0H_1+H_0$, where I have used the symmetry to change the order of matrix multiplication. But, would this not mean that I need to have $H_0-2H_0H_1=-H_0\iff H_0=H_0H_1\iff H_1=I$, which means that the matrix is, in fact, not idempotent, since $H_1$ is not necessarily equal to $I$? Thank you for your time.

Comment: The claim is FALSE, e.g. $\,0-I\,$ is not idempotent.

Comment: I don't think the zero matrix is a valid example of a hat matrix in the context of statistics.

Comment: Fine, the claim is still false. Consider two idempotent 2x2 matrices, both having three $0$s and the left upper corner, and the lower right corner, equal to $1$, respectively. Then the difference is not idempotent.

Comment: I think in the context of statistics, they must have non-zero diagonal entries, so that would not hold, either. I don't mean to be pedantic, sorry if it comes across that way. Isn't my conclusion that $H_1=I$ correct, though?

Comment: $H_0 = H_0 H_1$ does NOT imply $H_1=I$ unless $H_0$ has a left inverse, and of course hat matrices don't. $\qquad$

Comment: @WlodAA : Here is one of the advantages of knowing the larger context: These are hat matrices such as those arising in statistics. That would tell you which hypothesis the poster should have stated by didn't. So you are right that the proposition is false without the missing hypothesis, but that is of interest only if you make it an occasion to point out that that hypothesis is missing.

Comment: @WlodAA : The zero matrix could be considered a trivial hat matrix, and the proposition you seek to prove is still true if the zero matrix is used. But you omitted a hypothesis that would imply that Wlod's example is not a valid counterexample: The column space of $H_0$ is a subspace of that of $H_1.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need an additional hypothesis: The column space of $H_0$ is a subset of the column space of $H_1.$

If $H_0$ and $H_1$ are $n\times n$ symmetric idempotent matrices and the column space of $H_0$ is a subset of the column space of $H_1,$ then $H_0 H_1 = H_1 H_0 = H_0.$

If $x$ is in the column space of a symmetric idempotent real matrix $H,$ then $Hx=x,$ and if $x$ is orthogonal to the column space, then $Hx=0.$

If $x$ is any of the columns of $H_0$ and the aforementioned additional hypothesis holds, then $H_1 x = x.$ The columns of $H_1H_0$ are therefore just the columns of $H_0,$ so $H_1H_0= H_0.$ And since these matrices are symmetric, we also have $H_0 H_1=H_0.$

**If** $H_0$ had a right inverse matrix $A,$ then we could write:
$$
\require{cancel}
\xcancel{
\begin{align}
H_1 H_0 & = H_0. \\[6pt]
(H_1 H_0) A & = H_0 A = I. \\[6pt]
H_1 (H_0A) & = I. \\[6pt]
H_1 I & = I. \\[6pt]
H_1 & = I.
\end{align}}
$$
But no matrix with the same number of columns as rows has a one-sided inverse unless it has a two-sided inverse, and these don't.

Comment: Michael, could you, please, **start** with stating clearly and cleanly the result. (Then, I hope, I'll be able to follow your text.)

Comment: Thank you, I think I need to brush up on my linear algebra. I had quite forgotten about column spaces and subsets thereof. Very clear explanation.

Comment: @WlodAA : If $H_0$ and $H_1$ are $n\times n$ symmetric idempotent matrices and the column space of $H_0$ is a subset of the column space of $H_1,$ then $H_0 H_1 = H_1 H_0 = H_0. \qquad$

Comment: +1. Thank you. (Isn't symmetry a bit restricting?)

Comment: @WlodAA : Yes, the hypothesis of symmetry can actually be dropped. But hat matrices arising in statistics are symmetric, and apparently that is where the problem came from.

Answer (score 1):

Please, state the assumptions as it is done in (pure) linear algebra.

First of all, if two square matrices of the same dimension,$\,A\,\,B,\,$ are different then $\,A-B\,$ or $\,B-A\,$ is not idempotent.

For the time being, I still claim that the stated theorem is FALSE; that it is possible to have the two differences between two idempotent matrices $\,A\,B\,$ taken in either order, $\,A-B\,$ and
$\,B-A,\,$  neither has to be idempotent even in the case of 2x2 matrices which don't have $0'$s on the diagonal:

Let

$$ A\,\, =\,\, \left[\begin{array}{cc}
       \frac23 &  \frac23\\  \frac13 &  \frac13
   \end{array}\right] $$

and $\,B\,$ be the transpose of $\,A$:

$$ B\,\, =\,\, \left[\begin{array}{cc}
       \frac23 &  \frac13\\  \frac23 &  \frac13
   \end{array}\right] $$

Then both these matrices are idempotent, and

$$ A-B\,\, =\,\, \left[\begin{array}{cc}
       0 &  \frac13\\  -\frac13 &  0
   \end{array}\right] $$
while

$$ (A-B)^2\,\, =\,\, \left[\begin{array}{cc}
       -\frac19 &  0\\  0 & -\frac19
   \end{array}\right] $$

which means, indeed, that neither $\,A-B\,$ nor $\,B-A\,$ is
idempotent.   ***Great!***

> ***REMARK***   There is an entire class of idempotent 2x2 matrices $\,A\,B\,$ such that $\,A-B\,$ or $\,B-A\,$ is idempotent hence I made sure to avoid this confusing situation.

Comment: You are of course correct here, and I was under no impression that the result I'm trying to achieve holds for any two idempotent matrices. As it turns out, the defining characteristics of the two matrices I was investigating were not fully laid out by me, my mistake.